# онлайн интерпретатор Python

Tags: python

Посоветуйте онлайн интерпретатор для Python, чтобы можно было ввести и выполнить сценарий, вместо построчного варианта с консолью.

Comment: ideone.com и codepad.org не подходят?

Comment: я там уже пробовал, тот код, который запускается у меня в среде Python на ПК, на сайте не работает, выдает ошибки

Comment: да, там не всякий код можно запустить, но почти всегда все мои примеры работают.

если Вы пишете "не работате" - нужно писать что, иначе никто не поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда-то давно пользовался https://www.pythonanywhere.com Судя по письмам, падающим периодически в почту, они его ещё прокачали.